# Testing FormArray

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, karma-jasmine, angular-cli

I have a `PhoneNumbersFormComponent` whose template looks like :

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
    <div formArrayName="numbers">
      <input formControlName="countryPrefix">
      <input formControlName="number">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to pass the default test created by angular-cli's `ng g component xxx`

The first error I got was:

> Cannot find control with name 'countryPrefix'

Which I solved with:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PhoneNumbersFormComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.phoneNumbers = [];
    component.form = new FormGroup({
      countryPrefix: new FormControl(),
      number: new FormControl()
    });
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

Now the last remaining error is:

> Cannot find control with name 'numbers'

And I have no idea how to test `formArrayName="numbers"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
let array: FormGroup[] = [];
array.push(new FormGroup({
      countryPrefix: new FormControl(),
      number: new FormControl()
}));
let formArray = new FormArray(array);
component.form = new FormGroup({
       numbers: formArray // or array not totally sure
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can build a FormArray in your component and provide a getter for the form array.

```
ngOnInit() { this.formArrayOfPhoneNumbers = this.phoneNumbers.map((phone) => 
    { return new FormGroup({ countryPrefix: [phone.countryPrefix], number: [phone.number] })
}

get numbers: FormArray { return this.formArrayOfPhoneNumbers as FormArray }
```

I'm not exact on the syntax most likely, but the point is that the formArrayName directive will call the getter and you can ensure that a FormArray object is being returned.