# how to write unit test for FormArray in form

Tags: angular6, karma-jasmine

I have Login Page.

Structure as below:

- FirstName:
- LastName:
- Address:

  - Street:
  - Contact number:
  - Email:

I have create Address using FormArray. I'm trying to write uni test case to check field empty in Address array.
I tried accessing the value as

`let street = component.form.controls['address].get('Street'); expect(street.valid).toBeFalsy();`

Showing error as

> cannot read property valid of undefined

Comment: Possible duplicate [Testing FormArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46723685/testing-formarray)

Comment: Thanks for response. I have checked that link and created formArray and added to component. But i could get the value ex : i want get the value of street so i tried let fullNm = component.form.get('address').controls['Street'] throwing error as "cannot read value of undefined"

Comment: An address might be better suited to a FormGroup because it's a set of values that make up the whole. Use a FormArray when you need multiple of the same thing, i.e. a list of addresses for home, work, school, etc.